# Is it possible to do link unfurling when the target domain is the same as the app's web service?

Tags: microsoft-teams

The same server I use for my app can also serve up other pages. I would like to use link unfurling to add a card when any links to those pages are added to a message. My link unfurling works so long as the domain is something other than the app's server domain. When it is the same I can see in the debug output on my server that MS Teams  tries to open the link.

After more testing I found that my handler does get called but the card is not inserted. If I start a new message and paste the URL in again the card does appear even though no call was made to my service.

My manifest looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "version": "1.25",
  "id": "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
  "packageName": "xxxxxxx",
  "developer": {
    "name": "xx",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.xx.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://xxxx.com/en/privacy-policy/",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://xxxx.com/en/terms-and-conditions/"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "xxxxxxx",
    "full": "xxxxxxx"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "xxxxxxx",
    "full": "xxxxxxx"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "xxxxxxx-outline.png", 
    "color": "xxxxxxx-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
      "commands": [
      ],
      "messageHandlers": [
      {
        "type": "link",
        "value": {
          "domains": [
          "*.xxxxxxx.net",
          "*.ngrok.io"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
    }
  ],
   "validDomains": [
   "*.xxxxxxx.net",
     "*.ngrok.io"

  ]
}
```

This is my handler:

```
const { TeamsActivityHandler, CardFactory } = require('botbuilder');


class TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {


     handleTeamsAppBasedLinkQuery(context, query) { 
                console.log(`\nhandleTeamsAppBasedLinkQuery: `  + query.url);
        var parts = query.url.split("/");
        var sizeStr = parts[6].replace("-", " ");;
        var dir = parts[7];     
        var file = parts[8];

        var card = {
            contentType: 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero',
            content: { 
                title: 'File: ' + file,
                subtitle:'Dir: ' + dir,
                text: 'Size: '+ sizeStr
            }
        };

        console.log(card);
        const result = {
          attachmentLayout: 'list',
          type: 'result',
          attachments: [card]
        };

        const response = {
          composeExtension: result
        };
        return response;
      }
 }
module.exports.TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot = TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot;
```

I am using ngok while testing, is there any chance that it is caching things? I have seen some other strange behavior where Teams was unfurling links using a card that was already inserted and never calling my service, I know because the service was not even running.

I have found that if I run Teams in a browser the inspector shows the following errors:

```
Content Security Policy: Ignoring "'unsafe-inline'" within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified
GEThttps://eu-api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects/0-neu-d9-f79c02c35893b017803e3a0781c147c0/views/imgpsh_fullsize
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

Content Security Policy: Ignoring "'unsafe-inline'" within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified 2
Content Security Policy: Ignoring "'unsafe-inline'" within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified
[Bot invoke failed]: <BotError>Bot returned unsuccessful status code NotFound 3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:4:1729883
    postInvokeMessageWithUserInfo https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:4
    jQuery 4
        f
        g
        $eval
        $digest
    $digest https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:4
    jQuery 4
        $apply
        m
        x
        onload
{…}
​
errorCode: 1008
​
errorMessage: "<BotError>Bot returned unsuccessful status code NotFound"
​
errorSubCode: undefined
​
headers: {…}
​​
"cache-control": "no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache"
​​
"content-length": "87"
​​
"content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
​​
contextid: "tcid=965107910583198700,server=DB3PEPF000012A0,cv=ViFTxnq4MUSzogp8N8o9zg.1.0"
​​
pragma: "no-cache"
​​
"set-registrationtoken": "**redacted**"
​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
statusCode: 502
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
 undefined 0-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114:37
2020-06-16T21:13:53.449Z InputExtensionService: Input extension invoke command failed 0-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114:37
    e jQuery
    logMessage https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:4
    error https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:4
    runCommand https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:3
    jQuery 4
        f
        g
        $eval
        $digest
    $digest https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:4
    jQuery 4
        $apply
        m
        x
        onload
2020-06-16T21:14:43.904Z StorageUsage: Error ocrrured collecting storage usage numbers for the user. Error:navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.queryUsageAndQuota 0-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114:37
    e jQuery
    logMessage https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:4
    error https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:4
    startStorageUsageCollector https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:4
    _resolveFailures https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-84b23e5.js:942
    r https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-84b23e5.js:942
    _resolveFailures https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-84b23e5.js:942
    _resolveFailures https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-84b23e5.js:942
    _addCallbackSet https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-84b23e5.js:942
    then https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.1-app.min-84b23e5.js:942
    startStorageUsageCollector https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashedjs/3.2-app.min-0f0e437.js:4
    jQuery 3
        n
        e
        c
```

Comment: Could you please share the piece of code which you are trying?

Comment: I have added some code along with errors reported when using the web app.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of all of this was that my free subscription had quietly expired and I had not noticed it. :(